# How to scrape specific strings

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to scrape a website, for the terms ("cats", "dogs", "zebra"),
how do I do this? I want it the result to be all the instances of the given string, & maybe even a count. I could only find ways to do it by tags, but not inside of the tags.
What program or gem should I use?

Comment: I looked at nokogiri, mechanize, selectorgadget tutorials and videos, and searches, but could only find examples where they get the whole piece in between the tags.

Comment: "do it by tags, but not inside of the tags" is confusing. What does "inside of the tags" mean? Inside the tag's parameters or in the tag's child nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is our document:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<p>dogs</p><p>cats</p><p>zebra</p><p>bar</p><p>zebras</p><p>foo</p>')
```

The `content` is:

```
"dogscatszebrabarzebrasfoo"
```

Using `scan` gives us an array of the occurrences of a string:

```
doc.content.scan('dogs')
[  
    [0] "dogs"
]
```

Combining all that:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<p>dogs</p><p>cats</p><p>zebra</p><p>bar</p><p>zebras</p><p>foo</p>')
%w[dogs cats zebra].each do |a|
  puts '%d %s' % [doc.content.scan(a).count, a]
end
```

will output:

```
1 dogs
1 cats
2 zebra
```

While this sample makes it look like it'd be easy to parse your result using a regex against the original HTML, that path leads to madness. HTML is much too irregular to use patterns for scanning, and the opportunity for false-positives is too high. Stick with a parser, use it to extract the content, then work against that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ruby for this, Nokogiri / Mechanize should be the tools you should be using. Website scraping is pretty simple using these tools.

You could also do this using javascript which I feel is the simplest way to go about this.

Check this link out - http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs/

I had implemented a simple screen scraping using this and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need regular expressions. Regular expressions are written to match against a given string. Hopefully this will get you started

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

PHP lib which I find easy to use is http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

See the examples in the link.